# Confused about ACF import/export workflow

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

After spending time browsing forum threads I'm still confused about `Advanced Custom Fields`' PHP/JSON import/export functionality (docs [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/register-fields-via-php/), [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/synchronized-json/) and [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/local-json/)). For instance between PHP and JSON export methods:

1. Which one saves field definition and which one saves field data?
2. Which one writes into the database and which one doesn't?
3. More importantly, why do imported fields (created on a different server) show up in the dashboard in some cases, but frustratingly not in others?

I saw in certain threads that there are people who are confused about at least one of these aspects too. Could someone sum up exactly how this works?

For the record, my team wants total sync on every developer's machine, that is, we want to see the same thing in ACF settings and in the admin pages, everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

1. None of the methods export DATA. They're exporting FIELDS. To export data you have to use Export under Tools menu in WordPress dashboard (that place where you can export your posts or pages)
2. As above, none.
3. PHP exported fields are not showing in dashboard (ACF dashboard, so you can't edit them).

Comment: Thanks a lot @yzoja. Could you suggest a workflow allowing us to stay synced in ACF dashboard though? Notifying collaborators at every ACF field edit so they import JSON is too laborious (and feels a little antiquated). Pushing new JSON to an "acf-json" folder only adds "sync available" in ACF settings, which doesn't really solve the problem since the import is still manual and more importantly not everybody will see that notification (not quickly enough anyway)

Comment: I work alone, so I have no idea really. I mean, nothing sure. Maybe a git-synced database and those php/json ACF fields? but honestly, I'm just guessing, I never needed that.

Comment: JSON import does write in the DB.